# Protractor is giving 'Failed: The value of "value" is out of range.' while uploading pdf or xlsx file using sendkeys

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to upload some files in an input field using the following code:
`let absolutePath = helper_files.resolvePath('../../${file}');
 elements_contacts.EO.input_profile_picture.sendKeys(absolutePath);`
It runs fine on a local computer but whenever I try to run it on jenkins, it throws an error

> Failed: The value of "value" is out of range. It must be >= -2147483648 and <= 2147483647. Received 2423642698

[image]

Comment: is the file you are trying to upload is within the project folder?

Comment: yes, file is there.